# What is the standard build tool in Erlang?

Tags: build, erlang, makefile, rebar

I am very new to Erlang programming language. Is there a standard build tool in Erlang?

I have googled out these, not sure which one I should use.

- Erlang Make http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/make.html
- Rebar
- Erlang.mk

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rebar is gradually being replaced by [rebar3](http://rebar3.org), which provides more deterministic builds and conflict resolution, packages (integrating with hex.pm), and so on.

As one of the current rebar and rebar3 maintainers, I'd recommend rebar3.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can use default make tool for build yours code (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/make.html). But it is not so convenient.

Most projects use rebar. Because it is easy and convenient.

And yes, we can use Erlang.mk, it also provides the necessary functionality. It's big Makefile.

I recommend you start with rebar.

Answer (score 0):

rebar3 is a tool to make Erlang projects easier to manage. A kind of build tools and package management for erlang. This is also very helpful when we start a project, create a project skeleton, do compilation and build projects, make packages release to production, download erlang packages, etc.